# Hidden property in *NgIf directive

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have noticed in the following code, when the input field is correct filled and I submit the form, it shows the hidden message. Same happens when I go back to the page (after submit) the hidden field is visible. But i dont want to show the error message in this case. How can I change that?

```
   <form #userForm="ngForm">
      <ion-item *ngIf="useUser">
        <ion-label style="font-size: 12px" stacked>Username:</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user"name="username" #username="ngModel"  maxlength="20 required></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

     <p *ngIf="!useUser" [hidden]="username?.valid || submitted == false" color="danger" padding-left>
             Username required!
      </p>
```

**Angular2 code**

```
submit(form) {
      this.submitted = true;

      if (form.valid) {

     }
    }
```

Comment: "go back to page", what do you mean by that? Of course if you navigate to page, and the form is empty (again), the error message will show.

Comment: But why it's not shown when im visiting the page on first time? It should be handeld like visiting the page on the first time.

Comment: Based on what we are seeing, we can't do much debugging. You should try and reproduce the issue in a plunker.

Comment: When I could handle with it.. im gonna try today.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem in submit==false. I am not sure. Please try this.

```
[hidden]="username?.valid && submitted == 'false'" color="danger"
```

Comment: When I do it in this way, the hidden field is constantly visible.

Comment: please try this .

Comment: Still does not work, same issue (constantly visible)